# Seguridad de sesiones java: ¿Se almacenan en servidor o en cliente? ¿Pueden ser modificadas por el usuario?

Tags: java, web, java-ee, sesiones

Creo que el titulo es bastante descriptivo.
Las sesiones de java. ¿Se almacenan del lado del cliente o del lado del servidor? En caso se almacenarse del lado del cliente (en el navegador web), ¿Corren el riesgo de ser editadas? Si es así, ¿que contramedidas se puede tomar?

Tengo que usar sesiones para guardar información que en caso de ser modificada por agentes externos, permitiria al usuario a acceder a lugares restringidos. De ahi la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudarte con este concepto.

Para mi las sesiones no se almacenan en ningún lado, se crean, por lo que sirve para almacenar información entre diferentes peticiones HTTP, estas son las GET Y POST por lo que viajará hasta el terminó de la petición del Cliente o como también la puedes destruir.

Entiendo que quieres restringir acceso a ciertas partes de tu página web, esto lo puedes hacer muy bien con un Filter de Java y ahí mismo puedes asignar la sesión con la información que quieres que se comparta de ahí en adelante.

Saludos!!